# Pytorch: Randomly subsample loss tensors using `torch.randperm`

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to randomly subsample the `prediction` and `target` array for my loss calculation.

```
idx = torch.randperm(target.shape[0]) 
target = target.index_select(0, idx[0, sample_size]
```

However I'm getting this error message.

```
index_select(): argument 'index' (position 2) must be Variable, not torch.LongTensor
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

**Edit:**
I got one step closer. It seems like torch.randperm does not return a torch variable, so one has to explicitly convert the output:

```
idx = torch.randperm(target.shape[0]) 
idx = Variable(idx).cuda()
target = target.index_select(0, idx[0, sample_size]
```

only problem is now that the backpropagation fails. Seems like the operation of randomly subsampling is causing an issue with the dimensions. 
However the dimensions seem to be fine when calculating the loss:

```
loss = F.nll_loss(prediction, target.view(-1)) # prediction shape is [Nx12] and target shape is N
```

Unfortunately when calling `loss.backward()` I get this error message:

```
RuntimeError: The expanded size of the tensor (12) must match the existing size (217456) at non-singleton dimension 1
```

Comment: Not sure if I follow, but why not just use 
`idx = torch.randperm(target.shape[0])`

`target = target[idx[:sample_size]]` this samples `sample_size` samples from `target`, uniformly.

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me the same error

Comment: What is `target` like? I didn't get any error when I set `target = torch.ones(100)`

Comment: You are right, I had an error in the target dimensions! Thanks for the hint! Should I delete my question? (It's based on a bug)

Comment: I'm sure you can leave it, maybe someone has a similar problem and they'll notice their error